# Is it possible to update the flow field for different tuning wake parameters?

Tags: floris

Quite straightforward question. We can change some properties of turbine with `fi.reinitialize_flow_field`. You may also set the wake model directly on the script with (according to what I understood from the docs):
`floris.farm.set_wake_model('curl')`

So, is there any similar method to perform the same for the tuning wake parameters? I mean, change their values directly on script without having to go through the input file and change manually.

Comment: For clarification, do you mean wake model parameters (tuning parameters, expansions parameters, etc.)? Or parameters of the atmosphere/flow (wind speed, wind direction, TI, etc.)?

Comment: @bayc I mean the tuning wake parameters. Edited the post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are methods to get and set the wake model parameters programatically, without having to edit the input file directly. An example is provided in the latest FLORIS version under `floris/examples/_getting_started/example_03_get_and_set_model_parameters.py`. A dictionary of parameters for the currently set model can be obtained through the FLORIS interface object by using:

```
import floris.tools as wfct


# Initialize the FLORIS interface fi
fi = wfct.floris_interface.FlorisInterface("../example_input.json")

# Get the current model parameters
model_params = fi.get_model_parameters()
```

This dictionary can be modified and fed back to the FLORIS interface object by using:

```
fi.set_model_parameters(model_params)
```

If you simply want to view the current model parameters, you can use the method:

```
fi.show_model_parameters()
```

Please see the example for further details on the functionality available to explore the model parameters.